# Pinch focal point is always at the center of screen on IOS simulator no matter where is the mouse

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

When my React Native swiper component tested on MacOS IOS simulator, the focal point of pinch gesture handler 2.8.x remains at the center of the screen. no matter where the mouse was at when pinch starts.

```
const pinch = useMemo(() => Gesture.Pinch()
      .onUpdate((event) => {
        console.log("pinch event : ", event); <<==console output below
        //focalX.value = event.focalX;
        //focalY.value = event.focalY;
        focalX.value = event.focalX - width / 2;
        focalY.value = event.focalY - height / 2;
        console.log("focal X & Y :", `${focalX.value}, ${focalY.value}`);
        //
        scale.value = event.scale;
        
      })
      .onEnd((event) => {
        scale.value = withTiming(1);
        //focalX.value = withTiming(width/2);
        //focalY.value = withTiming(height/2);
        focalX.value = withTiming(0);
        focalY.value = withTiming(0);
        //translateX.value = withTiming(0);
      })
      .simultaneousWithExternalGesture(pan)   //work together with pan gesture
    );

    const swipeStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            transform: [{ translateX: translateX.value}]  //for swipe
        }
    }, []);

    const pinchStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      return {
        transform: [
          
          { translateX: -width / 2 },
          { translateY: -height / 2 },
          { translateX: focalX.value },
          { translateY: focalY.value },
          //{ translateX: (-width / 2 + focalX.value)},
          //{ translateY: (-height / 2 + focalY.value)},
          { scale: scale.value },
          { translateX: width / 2 },
          { translateY: height / 2 },
          { translateX: -focalX.value },
          { translateY: -focalY.value },
          //{ translateX: (width / 2 - focalX.value)},
          //{ translateY: (height / 2 - focalY.value)},
          
        ],
      };
    }, []);
```

Here is the console output of the pinch event:

```
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 422, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.7374383700947889, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.7056370484509342}
 LOG  focal X & Y : -1, 0
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 421, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.740944242474701, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.46044559120521955}
 LOG  focal X & Y : -1, -1
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 421, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.7444500429055128, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.07725808438373323}
 LOG  focal X & Y : -1, -1
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 421, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.7548519577722757, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.229177699659858}
 LOG  focal X & Y : -1, -1
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 422, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.7583581018064256, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.4440321988187737}
 LOG  focal X & Y : -1, 0
 LOG  pinch event :  {"eventName": "2259onGestureHandlerEvent", "focalX": 194, "focalY": 421, "handlerTag": 28, "numberOfPointers": 2, "scale": 1.761864252971071, "state": 4, "target": 2259, "velocity": 0.1457292133467874}
```

Here in output, the focalX and focalY remains at 194 & 241. When pinching, I hold both alt and command keys. But the focal point is always at the center of the screen no matter where the mouse was at.